# Audio recorded from Chrome doesn't play on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, safari, html5-audio

I'm building an app using React Js where it can record audio from users, upload the file or blob to cloud storage, and play the recorded audio from the file URL.

The issue is when the audio is recorded from Chrome, it only plays on Chrome but doesn't play in Safari.
On other hand, **if the audio is recorded from Safari, it plays just fine on both browsers.**

Tested on

- macOS 11.5.1 Big Sur
- Google Chrome Version 94.0.4606.81 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Safari Version 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.3)

Here is the implementation.

Recording part:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', ({ data }) => {
  const audioBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
  // or new File([audioBlob], 'name.mp3', { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
  // upload blob or file to server
});

// on start
recorder.start();

// on stop
recorder.stop();
recorder.stream.getTracks().forEach((i) => i.stop());
```

Playback part;

```js
const audioInstanceRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  audioInstanceRef.current = new Audio();
}, []);

const play = (url: string) => {
  if (!audioInstanceRef.current) return;

  audioInstanceRef.current.src = url;
  audioInstanceRef.current.play();
};
```

These were the requests Safari made to get **the audio recorded from Chrome**

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I tried to play with `audio.play()`, I've got this error message in console.

[image]

When I tried to play with `<audio />` element, there was no error message in console but instead `stall` event was fired.

[image]

I've also created mp3 file using `File` contructor and downloaded to macbook.
The mp3 file recorded from Safari was playable, where as the one recorded from Chrome was not.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All MIME types supported by MediaRecorder in Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739837/all-mime-types-supported-by-mediarecorder-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I'm stuck on the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the content type headers correctly - `audio-mpeg` is not correct. Safari is very picky about the Content-Type headers.  If they do not match the actual content type of the audio file, it will not play.

This is what I am using for my mp3 files. Be aware that Wav and Ogg formats require different headers.

audio/mpeg3;audio/x-mpeg-3;video/mpeg;video/x-mpeg;

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's wild that this information isn't more widely available. According to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66439066/3750636), there is no audio format that is both recordable and playable on every major browser.

At least from my experimentation. WebM recorded audio works on all browsers except Safari (though, Safari will still play some webms, just not the ones recorded using MediaRecorder. It might be an encoding thing, but I haven't nailed that down).

Ditching MediaRecorder was the only thing that worked for me. As said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73609977/3750636), using a different library like https://github.com/closeio/mic-recorder-to-mp3 works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and after trying around for quite a while I finally solved it:

When uploading to storage (in my case Firebase), type AND!!! file ending have to be webm...

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type: 'audio/webm'})
const audioPath = `${filename}.webm`
const fileRef = ref(storage, audioPath)
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(fileRef, audioBlob)
```

UPDATE:
this only fixed the issue on Safari for desktop, still not working on iOS

Answer (score 0):

It's not because you define your blob as "audio/mpeg" that it will actually be encoded as mp3. I struggle with the same problem... The problem is safari is not actually using the same codec.